# How to copy all files created between two dates using Command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

I have written code in window batch file (eq. getFiles.bat ) that get all files within select date range.
eq.

```
xcopy /S /D:01-10-2011  *.* C:\todaysFiles
```

But I want get all files in between two dates including **From date** and **To date**.

 file extension is .cmd or .bat

Comment: You probably want to edit your question to specify "get all files *changed* between two dates" or "get all files *created* between two dates".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're on Vista/Win7/WinServer2008 you can use `robocopy` like so:

```
robocopy c:\source c:\destination *.* /MAXAGE:20101231 /MINAGE:20111001
```

On XP, I'm not sure if there are built-in solutions short of using Powershell and the like.

Comment: Thanks Guido Domenici. right now I m using XP. I'll trie and back to u if any problem.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the file in time range?

Comment: @AshokD ask with Mention @<username>

Comment: There is some dispute as to whether `/MINAGE` and `/MAXAGE` is for date modified or date created, see https://serverfault.com/questions/419300/robocopy-minage-and-maxage. As this forms the basis of the question, it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Is there a way to make robocopy give feedback?

Comment: Hint: add `/E` for recursion into subfolders

Answer (score 2):

The title of this question is slightly misleading. Based on the questioner's `xcopy` example, I believe the questioner wants to know "How to **copy** all files created...", not how to **get** all files (which I equate with **list**).

The questioner also states "file extension is .cmd or .bat". This could mean that the questioner wants to copy only files with these extensions but I think it means the questioner would like a batch script solution.

To use the following solution, open a command prompt and `chdir` to the folder where the files to be copied are located. Then enter the commands listed below, changing the `SET` values as appropriate.

```
SET DESTINATION=C:\destination
SET DATE_FROM=01/01/2005
SET DATE_TO=01/01/2007
> nul forfiles /S /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con ( echo @path && copy /V @path %DESTINATION% )"
```

Note: this will copy files in subfolders as well as files in the top-level folder.

The `SET` values could be hard-coded directly into the `> nul forfiles...` line, meaning only one line is required, but for clarity I've used variable substitution.

A caveat is that it is based on `date modified` (original question asked for `date created`)

Credit to **aschipfl** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535/1754517) for providing the inspiration for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `forfiles` command. It can search recursively in all subfolders `/s` for files created in the selected root folder `/p <Path>`, execute commands on the selected files `/c "<Command>"`, apply masks to search `/m <SearchMask>`, between a date range `/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]`

[more info here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-files-based-on-modified-time/), [and here](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_examples)

Comment: I do not think this can handle a date range

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch for viewing files by creation date by year. Easily changed to cmd prompt by removing the extra percentage symbols.

```
for %%a in (2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017) do (
for /f %%i in ('xxcopy i:\podcasts\*.* /LL /ZS /Q /FC /DA:%%a-01-01 /DB:%%a-12-31 ^| find /c /v ""') do echo %%a: %%i
)
```

Comment: note that xxcopy is not a native windows application