# FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'd like to use FORFILES in a cmd file, to act on all files after a given date thru "today".  I can use something like `forfiles /d +07/10/2013 /c "cmd /c echo @fname"` to act on everything after 7/10/13, but what I want is to just be able to calculate instead from 90 days before "today".

Is there a syntax for the date calculation that will work in a cmd file that will let me specify "x days before today" to feed into FORFILES?

I prefer to not use VBS (and found a code snippet that would work in VBS), though I could alternatively re-write my script for Powershell, but ideally I want to stick with cmd.

To clarify, "-90" would find all files older than 90 days; "+90" would find all files newer than 90 days -after- today (which is fundamentally useless, as files are rarely written with future dates), and "+7/30/2013" will find all files newer than 7/30/2013.  I want that last time period, preferably able to take a number-of-days variable passed to the CMD file, that would say "after x number of days before today", i.e. "in the last x days".  So instead of using the hard-coded date as shown above, I want to be able to calculate that date within the cmd file.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19213777/2098699).

Comment: Is a batch file that creates/runs/removes a VBS script, and then runs the forfiles command, any good?

Comment: I want to avoid VBS entirely, for several reasons, though I realize that I'm cutting off one way to do it.

Comment: Endoro, I think that works but I'm not sure I understand it. Seems that you are building a directory-list file & then removing the entries that are older than the date range. Is that correct?  That might actually be fine esp. in this case, I actually am after building a file list that I'm feeding to something else. Please clarify if I'm not parsing correctly, i.e. "how it works". OBTW, I thought I'd searched comprehensively for an answer before posting this question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FORFILES less than 4 days old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209663/forfiles-less-than-4-days-old)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you could do something like this:

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refdate
} | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Comment: I like the elegant powershell answer, but I've been waffling back & forth between doing this overall process as a cmd file, cmd file that calls a powershell script, or powershell script. After finding FORFILES I thought it was ideal, until I ran into this date issue, because I'm actually building a list of files without extensions, which will feed into some other commands.  Thanks for the nifty bit of code, either way.

Comment: `forfiles` could provide a viable solution if it weren't for the odd behavior you observed (which I consider a design bug). `CMD`/batch in general, however, is terrible at dealing with dates, so I simply wouldn't bother. Just go for PowerShell.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a work-around for the design flaw of `forfiles` concerning `/D +dd` days, supposing that no items can be modified in the future, and which is based on two nested `forfiles` loops and relies on the fact that `forfiles` sets the `ErrorLevel` in case no items match the provided search criteria:

```
rem Define minimum and maximum age in days here (0 means today):
set /A MINAGE=0, MAXAGE=90

set "MAXAGE=%MAXAGE:*-=%" & set "MINAGE=%MINAGE:*-=%" & set /A MAXINC=MAXAGE+1
> nul forfiles /D -%MINAGE% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M @file /D -%MAXINC% || > con echo @fdate  @file"
```

The outer `forfiles` loop iterates through items that are at least as old as given by variable `MINAGE`. The inner `forfiles` loop, which iterates once at most as it recieves the iterated file `@file` from the outer loop, returns the same file if it is also at least as old as `MAXINC` (equals `MAXAGE` plus `1`); if it is not, `forfiles` sets the `ErrorLevel` to `1`, which in turn is captured by the `||` operator that executes the following command, namely `echo`, only in case `ErrorLevel` has been set to a non-zero value.

Both `MINAGE` and `MAXAGE` must not be negative numbers (the commands `set "MAXAGE=%MAXAGE:*-=%"` and `set "MINAGE=%MINAGE:*-=%"` remove the minus sign in case). The interim variable `MAXINC` has been introduced in order to include the age specified by `MAXAGE` itself into the returned result.

The redirection `> nul` prevents the outer `forfiles` from returning empty lines and the inner one from returning items that fulfil its search criteria (because we are interested in those that do not). `2> nul` prevents the inner `forfiles` loop from returning error messages in case its search criteria are violated. `> con` overrides `> nul` for the `echo` command to actually return the required items.

The `if @isdir==FALSE` part filters out directories so that only files are processed. Change `FALSE` to `TRUE` if you want to process only directories; remove it completely if you want to process both.

Comment: Great work and love the explanation :) Might be worth stating that negative numbers are prevented with the 2nd/3rd set commands. Also, what are "redired items"? Required or redirected?

Comment: Thank you! I extended the description and fixed the typo as suggested...

Comment: This answer deserves so much more love. Great answer and explanation.