# forfiles newer than X days ago

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I want to move all `avi` files that were last edited 5 days or less from one directory to an other directory.

I got it working the other way around. I also want it to be fully automated so manually setting the date won't do for me.

What I've got so far is this:

```
forfiles -p "<directory1>" -s -m *.avi /d -5 /C "cmd /c move @file <directory2>"
```

Swapping sign of the `-5` doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 8.

Does anyone know a way to do this (with `forfiles` or differently)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296588/forfiles-date-after-date-calc-in-cmd-file)