# Why is my bat script deleting itself when I run it

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I have made a bat script as follows

```
cd "D:\ACT\ACTBKUP"
del /Q *.* 

FORFILES /P E:\ACT_Backups /M *.zip /D +1 /C "cmd /c del @D:\ACT\ACTBKUP"
```

The script is supposed to delete everything in "D:\ACT\ACTBKUP" and then move the newest zip folder to that same folder from E:\ACT_Backups. When I run this script from windows server 2012 it just disappears.

thanks

Comment: Where is the script located?

Comment: The script is located on the Desktop

Comment: And Windows is installed on the C:\ drive, right?

Comment: yes, the script is on the c drive.

Comment: I actually figured out that if I get rid of `*.*` in the del command, and ad D:\ACT\ACTBKUP then the delete command works great. But the Forfiles command doesn't work. Can someone help fix that?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything. What is it actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to switch to a directory that is located on a different drive, you need to use `cd /d` instead of just `cd`. If you do not do this, the directory will not change.

When you run a script by double-clicking on it, batch considers the current directory to be the directory where the script is currently located. Since you are not using the `/d` option with `cd`, you are running `del /Q *.*` on the directory where the script is located.

To fix this, you have two options:

```
cd /d "D:\ACT\ACTBKUP"
del /Q *.*
```

or

```
del /Q "D:\ACT\ACTBKUP"
```

---

There is no option in `forfiles` to get just the most recent file; `/D +1` will return all files with a last-modified date of today or later. In order to get the most recent file and nothing else, you will need a `for /f` loop:

```
rem /b returns just the file name and /o:d sorts the files by date
rem Since newest_file gets set for each .zip file in the directory,
rem the last file set will be the newest
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /o:d E:\ACT_Backups\*.zip') do set newest_file=%%A
copy %newest_file% D:\ACT\ACTBKUP
```

Comment: ok so here is my latest version. `del /Q D:\ACT\ACTBKUP
FORFILES /P "E:\ACT_Backups" /M *.zip /D +1 /C "cmd copy @files D:\ACT\ACTBKUP"` but the forfiles command is not coping the file. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Read the forfiles help output. There is no @files.

Comment: @DennisHertzler - Also, if you only want the most recent file, you need to adjust your code to what I've shown.

Comment: @DennisHertzler, besides the missing `/C` option after `cmd` and the wrong variable name `@files` instead of `@file` in your `forfiles` command line, I am pretty sure this is also because of the `/D +1` option; regard that `+1` means _items modified on today's date (day) + 1 or later = items modified tomorrow or later_, so it does not make any sense (unless you have a time machine; this is a stupid design flaw of `forfiles`); I guess you want to refer to _items modified yesterday or later_, right? to achieve that, refer to [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535)...

Comment: I would recommend using `@path` instead of `@file` because you're copying a file between two separate drives.