# ForFiles Newer Than Batch

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I'm working with the forfiles command

I am attempting to get a list of files newer than X days ago.

When I use the /D +X command I get a not files found error:

```
forfiles /P %filename% /D +3
```

However if I use a date it works fine:

```
forfiles /P %filename% /D +06/29/2016
```

Am I missing something on the +X formatting? It seems like it is adding 3 days to the current date and then looking for files newer than that.

Or is there a simpler way to increment the date than I'm aware of. Only work with Batch once in a while

I don't want to use vbs, and I would rather not have a set of code longer than the rest of my script just to get the date, there should be a simpler way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296588/forfiles-date-after-date-calc-in-cmd-file)

Comment: The `/D +X` command does not seem to work.  This means you have to try another method that requires trickier syntax.