# How to delete file in a particular folder between dates

Tags: batch-file

I am using this code for delete a particular folder(@RD /S /Q "D:\Remove a particular files\Test")

But how i will delete data only last 15-days data
I want to delete data between dates

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a free coding-site... And I highly recommend taking the [tour].

Comment: If "last 15-days data" means files last modified 15 days ago or later, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535); alternatively, you could use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) to move away matching files into some temporary directory, then deleting this using `rd /S /Q`...