# ForFiles command does not work with parameter /D +xx

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

This finds no files (two in the directory are only one day old):

```
for /d %%d in (%mydir%\*) do (
  cd %%d
forfiles /P %%d  /M *.ppt* /D +7 /C "cmd /c echo Converting @file"
)
```

When I change the `/D` parameter to `/D -6` it's ok,
also `/D 25.10.2021` is ok.

But `/D +7` never finds any file.

Is it a bug or feature?

Comment: Do you really have files that you created next week?

Comment: ah thats my problem.. i thought it show all new files from the last 7 days. you are right. i read the docs 3 times  .. my fault... sorry.

Comment: is there any way to show all files newer then 7 days ?

Comment: `forfiles`' `/D` option is useless with `+` and a number of days, because it looks for items modified in the future, which is of course useless without a time machine. But there is a work-around – take a look a this: [FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19296588)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which is an adaption of what looks like the same method shown in [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535) within the link in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786629/forfiles-command-does-not-work-with-parameter-d-xx#comment123360503_69786629).

```sh
@Set "MyDir=%UserProfile%\Videos"
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%MyDir%" /B /A:D 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('^"Dir /B /A:-D 1^>NUL 2^>^&1 ^&^& %SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%MyDir%\%%G" /D -0 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x22If @IsDir==FALSE %SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /M @File /D -8 1>NUL 2>&1 || Echo @Path0x22" 2^>NUL^"') Do @Echo Converting %%H
@Pause
```

*I have left out any explanation, as the answer linked above, explains the methodology, this essentially wraps that methodology within a `For /F` loop.*

Comment: you made my day ! Thanks ! Gracie ! Danke ! Merci !