# How can I have multiple date filters in a forfiles command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm trying to catch all the files in a folder taking in account two filters, the first one is the creation date have to be greater than 01/01/2020 and the creation date have to be lower that today-6.

I don't know how to apply two filters in the same `forfiles` command line.
This is what I have:

```
forfiles /P c:\temp /D +01/01/2020 /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Comment: Use PowerShell instead of trying to get a scripting language to perform tasks it was never designed to do. Also forfiles.exe, only works with last written/modified dates and times, not creation dates and times. There should be plenty of questions and answers with the [[tag:powershell]] tag, which can identify file objects within a created date/time range. Please use the search facility to adapt one or more to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) doesn't filter for the creation date, rather does it regard the last modification date (though not the time), and it supports only a single such filter.

However, you may nest two commands:

```cmd
forfiles /P "C:\TEMP" /D +01/01/2020 /C "forfiles forfiles /P @path\.. /M @file /D -6 /C 0x22cmd /D /C if @isdir==FALSE echo 00x7840path0x22" 2> nul
```

Note, that the expected date format behind `/D` depends on the actual locale settings.

Also refer to this post: [FORFILES date -after- (date calc in cmd file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585535)